# Adobe Illustrator script to execute multiple batches

Tags: javascript, batch-file, vector, svg

At my work, we have a tremendous amount of vector EPS files. The "powers that be" want them converted to SVG files as to have common file format, while maintaining current folder structures, that are compatible with all our various online and offline software.

I am using Illustrator CS6 for windows.

I am not very good at scripting and I am hoping that someone might be able to point me in the right direction. I am looking to develop a script (VBA or JS) that will launch a JS script and multiple batch actions (or another alternative to solve this issue). Looking below, you will find that this method is slow and cumbersome and requires better automation.

Basic Workflow

1. Manually copy folder (which includes subfolders) to create a working folder.
2. Execute (ugly) javascript that I have cobbled together that loads each EPS file and saves SVG to the EPS files location.
3. Execute batch file that rasterizes (high DPI) and then vectorizes the svg file. This is to merge all objects of the same color together. I used to use PATHFINDER: TRIM/MERGE to merge/punchout objects by color but found sometimes vector elements were lost instead of being punched out. The loss of detail using this new method is minimal and, more importantly, acceptable to the boss.
4. Execute batch action to remove the color white and perform other manipulations. I have not been able to combine this with the previous action as I have not been able to figure out how to access individual objects within the vectorized rasterize image until the file is saved and re-opened.
5. Execute batch file to re-align the vector with the artboard due to apparent long time bug in regarding SVG file conversion in Illustrator.

Any suggestions that anyone might have would be greatly appreciated.